# Change label text on FORM1.cs from another class c#

Tags: c#

I'm new in c# and don't know like anything. It's a program for proxy checking. I want to create a UI for it but the problem I'm having is that I can't pass like Good Results, Bad Results etc from the Program.cs to Form1.cs

My program UI is like this.

```
Good: 0
Bad: 0 
Retries: 0
```

I'm trying to sum `"Good"`, with `+ 1` every time a "Good" proxy its found. 
I don't know how to do that, I completed the program I just need to show the results on the UI.

Thank You

P.S Sorry for my bad English.

Edit:

I tried following but the labels text wont update.

Form1.Cs

I wrote this public functions :

```
  public void Good1()
    {
        good.Text = (Int32.Parse(good.Text) + 1).ToString();
        good.Refresh();

    }
```

And I called the function in the Program.cs as following

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();    
if(proxy == "live"){
// Some code here.
form1.Good1();
// Some other code here
}
```

But when I run the program it wont update the label text on the UI. It stays "0" as I wrote it.
I'm not good with C#, this is my first program with C# so I'm desperate.

Comment: You could try creating a public property within Form1.cs and writing to that from wherever your data is coming from. Then in the setter of that property change the text within your textbox. I presume you're using WinForms, in which case you can't change a form's control's properties from anywhere other than that form.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a winform tutorial. I think it's what you are using.

It's friendly use, you drag and drop your components. If you need to change the content, it's a textbox, not a label.

You have to change the textbox name to put something like TbxGoodProxy in the draw part and in the code behind you then could do something like TbxGoodProxy.Text = (Int32.Parse(TbxGoodProxy.Text) + 1).ToString();

Hope it's help